# Set selected item in React native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I add Picker items like the following:

```
 addLanguage() {
        console.log('addLanguage');
        pickerValue = this.state.pickerValue;
        pickers = this.state.pickers;
        // this.state.itemValues[0] = 'fr';
        itemValues = this.state.itemValues;
        pickers.push(<View key={Math.random()} style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>


            <Picker key={Math.random()} style={{width: 150}}
                    selectedValue={this.state.itemValues[0]}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                        this.setState({itemValue});
                        this.handleChangeOption(itemValue);
                    }}
                //   this.handleChangeOption(itemValue)}}
            >
                {
                    Object.keys(this.state.isoLangs).map((lang) => {
                        return <Picker.Item key={lang} label={this.state.isoLangs[lang].name} value={lang}/>
                    })
                }
            </Picker>
            <Image
                source={require('./assets/Arrow.png')}
            />

            <Picker key={Math.random()} style={{width: 150}}
                    onValueChange={(value) => {
                        this.setState({pickerValue: value});
                        pickerValue = value;
                    }}>
                {
                    Object.keys(this.state.isoLangs).map((lang) => {
                        return <Picker.Item key={lang} label={this.state.isoLangs[lang].name} value={lang}/>
                    })
                }
            </Picker>
        </View>);
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            pickers: pickers,
            //  itemValues:itemValues
            // pickerValue: pickerValue
        });
    }
```

It works to add new items but it doesn't work to set the selected item once an item is selected. What could be the matter? My complete code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, Picker, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableHighlight, View} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json
import {Constants} from 'expo';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.section1}>
                    <Text style={[styles.text, {paddingBottom: 20}]}>{'Welcome'}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.section2}>
                    <Text style={[styles.text, {paddingTop: 20}]}>{'Your verification was successful'}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.section3}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{'Sign up as:'}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.section4}>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>

                        <View style={styles.button}>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}>

                                <Image source={require('./assets/stck2.png')} style={styles.image}/>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}>

                                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{'Translator'}</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>

                        </View>


                        <View style={styles.button}>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Recruiter')}>

                                <Image source={require('./assets/stck1.png')} style={styles.image}/>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Recruiter')}>

                                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{'Recruiter'}</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>

                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //  this.state = { itemValue: this.prop.initialSelectedValue };
        this.handleChangeOption = this.handleChangeOption.bind(this);
        this.addLanguage = this.addLanguage.bind(this)
        this.update = this.update.bind(this)
    }

    state = {
        count: 0, itemValues: [], pickers: [], user: '',

        isoLangs: {
            "ab": {
                "name": "Abkhaz",
                "nativeName": "аҧсуа"
            },
            "aa": {
                "name": "Afar",
                "nativeName": "Afaraf"
            },
            "af": {
                "name": "Afrikaans",
                "nativeName": "Afrikaans"
            },
            "ak": {
                "name": "Akan",
                "nativeName": "Akan"
            },
            "sq": {
                "name": "Albanian",
                "nativeName": "Shqip"
            },
            "am": {
                "name": "Amharic",
                "nativeName": "አማርኛ"
            },
            "ar": {
                "name": "Arabic",
                "nativeName": "العربية"
            }
        }
    };

    getLanguageName = function (key) {
        key = key.slice(0, 2);
        lang = this.state.isoLangs[key];
        return lang ? lang.name : undefined;
    };
    getLanguageNativeName = function (key) {
        key = key.slice(0, 2);
        lang = this.state.isoLangs[key];
        return lang ? lang.nativeName : undefined;
    };

    handleChangeOption(itemValue) {
        console.log('itemValue ' + itemValue);
        console.log('1 this.state.itemValues ' + this.state.itemValues);

        this.state.itemValues[0] = itemValue
        console.log('2 this.state.itemValues ' + this.state.itemValues);

    }

    update() {
        console.log('update ' + this.state.itemValues);
        return this.state.itemValues[0] || 'ar';
    }

    addLanguage() {
        console.log('addLanguage');
        pickerValue = this.state.pickerValue;
        pickers = this.state.pickers;
        // this.state.itemValues[0] = 'fr';
        itemValues = this.state.itemValues;
        pickers.push(<View key={Math.random()} style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>


            <Picker key={Math.random()} style={{width: 150}}
                    selectedValue={this.state.itemValues[0]}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                        this.setState({itemValue});
                        this.handleChangeOption(itemValue);
                    }}
                //   this.handleChangeOption(itemValue)}}
            >
                {
                    Object.keys(this.state.isoLangs).map((lang) => {
                        return <Picker.Item key={lang} label={this.state.isoLangs[lang].name} value={lang}/>
                    })
                }
            </Picker>
            <Image
                source={require('./assets/Arrow.png')}
            />

            <Picker key={Math.random()} style={{width: 150}}
                    onValueChange={(value) => {
                        this.setState({pickerValue: value});
                        pickerValue = value;
                    }}>
                {
                    Object.keys(this.state.isoLangs).map((lang) => {
                        return <Picker.Item key={lang} label={this.state.isoLangs[lang].name} value={lang}/>
                    })
                }
            </Picker>
        </View>);
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            pickers: pickers,
            //  itemValues:itemValues
            // pickerValue: pickerValue
        });
    }

    render() {

        console.log('render: ');
        keys = Array.from(this.state.isoLangs);

        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>

                    <Text style={{
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: 'normal',
                        color: 'skyblue',
                    }}>
                        Which languages do you translate?
                    </Text>
                </View>


                {this.state.pickers.map((picker) => {
                    return picker
                })}


                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.addLanguage()}>
                    <Text style={{
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: 'normal',
                        color: 'skyblue',
                    }}>+ add language</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>

                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen3')}>
                        <Image
                            source={require('./assets/Next.png')}

                        />
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: HomeScreen,
        },
        Details: {
            screen: DetailsScreen,
        },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
    }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <RootStack/>;
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    section1: {
        flex: 0.17,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    section2: {
        flex: 0.30,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    section3: {
        flex: 0.10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    section4: {
        flex: 0.43
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 24,
        color: '#53a6db',
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingTop: 40,
        paddingBottom: 40,
        paddingLeft: 40,
        paddingRight: 40
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    button: {
        flex: 0.5,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 24,
        color: '#53a6db',
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingTop: 5,
        paddingBottom: 5,
        paddingLeft: 5,
        paddingRight: 5
    },
    image: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hardcoded the selectedValue to a variable that doesn't change: `selectedValue={this.state.itemValues[0]}`. I believe you want it to be `this.state.itemValue`.

Comment: It does not re-render when state is changed. It is a bug in react native. It says that components should re-render when the state is changed but it doesn't.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz  Did you make the change I suggested?

Comment: Yes. The Picker returns to the first choice if I try to use the Picker.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz I've tried writing a snack on expo to debug your issue. I would start your picker functionality from scratch because you've made it unnecessarily complicated. If you still have issues, create a snack, post it and I'll have a look when I get some time. Do not modify state by saying this.state.itemValues[0] = itemValue. Always modify state using this.setState. Good luck!